# What is the difference in meaning between 練習, 訓練 and 実践?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between 練習, 訓練 and 実践?

Answer (score 5):

**練習｛れんしゅう｝**： 学問｛がくもん｝、技芸｛ぎげい｝、運動｛うんどう｝、スポーツなどを、くり返｛かえ｝して習｛なら｝うこと。
A kind of practice to repeat study, an art, physical exercises, athletics or sports, and learn it

**訓練｛くんれん｝**： 習熟｛しゅうじゅく｝させるため、実際｛じっさい｝にその事｛こと｝をさせて鍛｛きた｝えること。
A kind of training where a trainer lets you really do something and lets you brush the skill of it up, in order to master it

**実践｛じっせん｝**： 実際｛じっさい｝の情況｛じょうきょう｝のもとでそれを行｛おこな｝うこと。
A kind of real activity to perform something under the real situation

Answer (score 5):

**実践** is clearly different from the other two. 実践 is *practice* as opposed to *theory*. It's *practice* as in "bring it into practice", "daily clinical practice", etc. It refers to actually doing something instead of thinking or simulating. 実践的 means *practical* as opposed to *theoretical*.

**練習** and **訓練** are similar and often interchangeable. But 練習 is closer to *practice* and 訓練 is closer to *training*. 練習 is actually doing some physical activity again and again to be able to perform it better. 訓練 tends to sound more organizational and/or occupational, and it sometimes includes learning something in a classroom. 訓練 does not necessarily imply you do one thing many times. If you've just bought your first guitar as a hobbyist, what you will do is usually called 練習. What an astronaut will do before going to the space is usually called 訓練. 訓練 often has a clear goal (an expert doesn't have to do 訓練), but 練習 is something you may have to do throughout your career.